# Find the height of the BST tree for given array preorder representation

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree

[image]

Example for the image above. Array representation in order is:8,3,1,6,4,7,10,14,13
I want to find out the height **without constructing the Tree**.....
Basically You have array representation of BST you need to find out the height of tree without constructing the tree?

Comment: Hi Prakash and welcome to Stack Overflow! It is good practice on the site to post some attempted solution to your question/problem, before a solution is provided to you. Could you please update your post with this information so that we can help you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question can be solved using a recursive approach, as most tree problems are solved.

Pseudo code-

```
int get_height(int a[], int low, int hi) {
   if(low > hi)
      return -1;

   int root = a[low];

   // Find position pos in the range (low+1) to hi such that 
   // all elements at left of pos are <= root and all elements at right 
   // of pos are > root. Do this using modified binary search

   int pos = <position for root found as described above>

   int ht = 1 + max (get_height(a, low+1, pos),
                     get_height(a, pos+1, hi));

   return ht;
}
```